# EclipseLink DDL generation for specific entities

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, ddl

Is there a way to tell EclipseLink DDL generation to only generate the DDL for specific entities?  The following code generates a createDDL.sql script for all entities, but I'd like to create one for just specific entities.

```
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-tables");
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "sql-script");
properties.put("eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name", "createDDL.sql");
```

Comment: I am not aware of some configuration for defining that, however I believe a workaround could be to define a persistence unit with just those entities and set the ddl-generation property there.